# More about hypsometry for large glaciers

Tags: glaciology, geomorphology

I am currently reading a paper which says

> The elevation ranges between 1700 and 2200 m show smaller
> relative surface changes than the elevation ranges between 2200
> and 3300 m. This has to be related to:

> > The biggest glaciers where the surface loss on the
> > glacier banks for a considered elevation range can be partly
> > counter-balanced by the surface elevation lowering introducing an
> > apparent shift of the contour lines.

What I want to understand is the "surface elevation lowering" phenomenon that the paper refers to.

Ref: Gardent, Marie, et al. "Multitemporal glacier inventory of the French Alps from the late 1960s to the late 2000s." Global and Planetary Change 120 (2014): 24-37.